# SAP PI 7.0 to 7.1 upgrade: 'Enter at least the mount point for the DVD title "Add-On CD"'

Tags: sap

I am upgrading from SAP PI 7.0 to PI 7.1 and it is asking me to:

**Enter at least the mount point for the DVD title "Add-On CD"**

Please can you tell me where I can find this CD? I have tried pointing it to SPS8 (and I have extracted all of the SAR and CAR files) but this has not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this. I did have the path to the correct CD mapped (the Upgrade CD - not labeled 'Add-in') but the path to the CD had to be under 30 characters. The instructions said under 40 characters.

I shortened the names of the directories to the CD to under 30 characters and it worked.